# How to properly call _vsnprintf from a DLL

Tags: c++

I am trying to execute a game function that displays text to the chat screen. I pulled the address from IDA that then calls _vsnprintf. I can get it to display text to the chat but its wonky random letters that changes whenever I mess with the argList. Heres the constructor for _vsnprintf.

```
int __cdecl _vsnprintf(char *const Buffer, const size_t BufferCount, const char *const Format, va_list ArgList) //0xA739FF
```

Whenever I change something in ArgList it changes the text result but the text displayed in chat is still random and wonky.

Also this is the function that calls _vsnprintf

```
int __cdecl print_to_chat(char *Buffer, size_t BufferCount, char *Format, char ArgList) //0x51D020
```

And here is the code I got so far

```
namespace bo2 {
    constexpr uintptr_t say = 0x7EB870;
    constexpr uintptr_t printf = 0xA739FF;
    using say_t = void(*)();
    using printf_t = void(*)(char* const Buffer, const size_t BufferCount, const char* const Format, va_list ArgList);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE instance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved) {
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        const auto say = reinterpret_cast<bo2::say_t>(bo2::say);
        const auto printf = reinterpret_cast<bo2::printf_t>(bo2::printf);
        char buf[255], format[255]; size_t size = 256; std::string rV = "does this work now??????";
        va_list list;
        va_start(list, rV);
        say();
        printf(buf, size, format, list);
    }
}
```

Any help?

I tried editing Format to get a proper display to chat text but that doesn't seem to be it after realizing whatever was edited in ArgList contributed to a proper yet random and wonky return of text to chat.

EDIT: Im now only calling _vsnprintf instead of print_to_chat and using va_list instead of const char* or char*

Comment: The `char ArgList` parameter in `print_to_chat` looks unusual. You sure you don't want `va_list ArgList`?

Comment: `const char* ArgList` also looks weird.

Comment: Side note: You almost always regret casting a function pointer. If you don't give a function exactly the types it wants, you're pretty much <expletive deleted>ed.

Comment: @user4581301 calling va_list in that function causes the same thing to happen, even in the _vsnprintf it just types wonky text still. But im gonna integrate it to using va_list instead because its definitely more proper and instead of trying to call print_to_chat im just gonna call _vsnprintf because it does the same thing minus a few jz and jnz calls on the stack.

Comment: @user4581301 ok, sorry I am a bit new to that, how should I go about calling it then?

Comment: Update the code to match what you're working with now. `constexpr uintptr_t printf = 0x51D020;` looks suspicious. Let the linker or dynamic linking do the addressing rigamarole for you. Trying to hardcode an address isn't stable. Stuff gets moved around all the time.

Comment: @user4581301 ok gonna work on that now and update any changes. Thanks!

Comment: My worry is that you are working to hard to abstract something and not telling us what or why in the question. For example, why not simply call `vsnprintf` directly? If you're trying to get more speed, worry about speed later. Get something that works and then see if you A) really need more speed and B) the changes you make are noticeably faster. Don't be the programmer who gets lost in the micromanaging of details and completely misses that the algorithm is too slow or the program is too IO bound for anything to help.

Comment: @user4581301 yes you are right, I am now just calling vsnprintf directly, I dont care about speed or anything external I just want some text of my choosing to be printed onto the chat. I just updated using va_list but im unsure if va_start macro is the way to initialize va_list properly. Any more helpful suggestions? Because now that i am calling vsnprintf and using a a va_list instead of a char* or const char* its causing the game to crash which is probably because I am initializing va_list wrong.

Comment: `va_start`'s second argument expects the last non-variable argument used when the function was called. It uses it to build the argument list list that's in the first argument. For `printf`-ish functions that's usually the format string, but it has nothing to do with the format string as a format string. It just wants to know where to start looking.  I've never tried feeing it anything but the last non-variable argument, or if I did it was t30-or-so years ago and I've long since forgotten what total smurf-show resulted.

Comment: [Here's some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start) with a  good, simple example of how to use it.